# Does anyone use Mix anymore?

Tags: solidity, mix, ide

I'd like to install Mix in order to get experience with a Solidity IDE and its debugger, but all indications I've seen so far are that installation is a real headache.  Am I right about that?  And given that Mix has been discontinued, is it even worth giving Mix a go?  Perhaps it's better to just get started with Remix?  Would actually really like to try Mix, but not if it effects my velocity in learning other Ethereum related subjects.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix is no more maintained as you mentioned, there is many other alternative to help you writing and compiling your contracts, the interesting alternative for beginners is [**Solidity Browser**](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/).
other available IDE are listed on the Doc : https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#available-solidity-integrations

I recommend you also to explore the **etherum studio** .
http://blog.ether.camp/post/142794388568/ethereum-studio-is-ready-for-you

please read also: [What is an IDE? What's the difference between mix, and browser based IDE?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-is-an-ide-whats-the-difference-between-mix-and-browser-based-ide)